# Is there any mode to update a kivy window individually?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, kivy

I have a kivy window, and I need to rotate a repeating loop"While" in code, but as expected, "While" stops the automatic update of the window, and as a result, locking it.
For example:

```
--- "loop window" ---


var = 0
while var <= 100:
     var += 1
     print(var)


--- "end of loop" ---
```

The problem is that the program has to wait for the loop to finish, and this is locking in the window. I know that in Tkinter has a function Youroot.update(), which updates the window whenever called, I want to know if kivy also owns, or something similar. Please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kivy, you should not run a loop like that on the main thread, so just run it on another thread (see [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html)). If you need to make a change to something in the kivy display from that thread, use [Clock.schedule_once()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) to schedule just that bit back on the main thread.

Comment: It's a solution, but I have problems with Thread in this case because I don't have full control over the loop. For example, when I try to close the window during the loop, it hangs completely. I just wanted a way to update every repetition, using the built-in code. Thanks for the attention!